# IIS7 pseudo streaming FLV with bit rate throttling

Tags: iis-7, flv, bandwidth-throttling, pseudo-streaming

I want to combine pseudo streaming of FLV videos with bandwidth control on IIS7.5.

Pseudo-streaming is the ability to seek/jump within a video although it has not been completely loaded, yet. It is explained here http://flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/pseudostreaming.html and the site also has a link to the source code of a custom c# IHttpHandler implementation that works nicely as managed handler in IIS7 integrated mode.

Now while this is working, the FLVs are transmitted with maximum speed which is not needed/wanted. Usually the Bit Rate Throttling module for IIS7 http://www.iis.net/download/BitRateThrottling solves this.

But in combination they do not work: the handler takes over and the module does not kick in. Is there any configuration to combine these two techniques to limit bandwidth while pseudo-streaming? Or any other custom implementation to limit bit rates near to the high quality of the IIS BRT module?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://forums.iis.net/p/1178020/1981309.aspx